# Jekyll Minimal Mistakes theme - Add plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jekyll, github-pages

so I know this is very specific, but since I am mostly new to programming on websites, I hope you can help me :) 
I am trying to integrate the jekyll-lunr-js-search (https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search) into the minimal-mistakes theme and having a few problems with it.

I followed the instructions for the search but already had problems there, since it seems mmistakes is already prepped to be on github-pages:

- There are just gh-pages conform plugins in the Gemfile.
- There is no _plugins folder
- The plugins used are in the /assets/js/plugins folder and just called via package.json where they are uglifyjs(ed)

So since I do not know much about the technology, I guess I would have to uglifyjs the jekyll-lunr-js-search js files too, but I am did not find a way to get this to work. There has no index.json been created.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I found was this [link](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2016/01/04/how-to-make-lunrjs-jekyll-work-together/) which makes the search easy in Jekyll on Github Pages.

It does not really solve the problem at hand but it gives me the beginning I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wrong file location

The `README.md` file at [jekyll-lunr-js-search](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search/blob/master/README.md#1b-install-by-copying-the-plugin-to-your-jekyll-site) mentions that you must place your `build/jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb` inside the `_plugins` folder in the root of your Jekyll site.

#### Plugins on GitHub Pages

However, all GitHub Pages sites are generated using the `--safe` option to disable custom plugins for security reasons. Unfortunately, this means Jekyll plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

(You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, but you’ll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files.)

You can only use [these plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/) on GitHub Pages.

#### Helpful resources

- https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/
- https://pages.github.com/versions/
- http://rayhightower.com/blog/2016/01/04/how-to-make-lunrjs-jekyll-work-together/

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is, that I can't get this to work even though I am following the manual in the README.md.
It seems to be the case that no index.json is created, so there is nothing to search through.